# Having clause using MAX not working as I would expect in HIVE query

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am trying to select records only matching the max DATE1 column in my table and the prior month.

I have tried writing this using the standard having clause syntax, this did not work so I was able to get the results I am expecting using a CTE. This solution should work for what I am trying to do but I would better like to understand why the HAVING clause is not working. In these examples MAX(DATE1)= 2018-02-28

Query that I was expecting to work

```
select
    ID,
    sum(money) as money,
    date1
from
    table1
group by
    ID,
    date1
having
    date1 between add_months(max(date1),-1) and max(date1)
```

This will return a result set similar to this

```
| ID | Money | date1      |
|----|-------|------------|
| 1  | 50    | 2017-12-31 |
| 2  | 600   | 2018-01-31 |
| 3  | 200   | 2018-02-28 |
```

This query using a CTE returns the expected result set

```
with period as (
    select
        max(date1) as maxdate1,
        add_months(max(date1),-1) as priordate1
    from
        table1 

select
    id,
    sum(money),
    date1
from
    table1
join period on
    1 = 1
where
    date1 between priordate1 and maxdate1
group by
    id,
    date1
```

Expected result set

```
| ID | Money | date1      |
|----|-------|------------|
| 1  | 50    | 2018-02-28 |
| 2  | 600   | 2018-01-31 |
| 3  | 200   | 2018-02-28 |
```

Comment: You are aggregating by `date1`, so `max(date1)` is the value in the row.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work because `date1` is in the `group by`.  You can use window functions to avoid the `join`:

```
select id, sum(money), maxdate1
from (select t1.*, max(date1) over () as maxdate1
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
where date1 between add_months(maxdate1, -1) and maxdate1
group by id, maxdate1
```

Comment: Thanks this explains why my first query is not working as I would have expected. It's only returning maxdate1. I think it is returning all of the correct records where date1 is max date and the prior month but it's displaying max date for all results. I'm going to fiddle around with it a bit more as this is a better solution than my join to a CTE on 1=1 if I can get it working.